# C# Linq - "field.Contains(...)" unknown on WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, where-clause, contains

```
var logView = (from ag in db.ARQUIVOGED
               join aglv in db.ARQUIVOGEDLOGVIEW on ag.ID_ARQUIVO_GED equals aglv.ID_ARQUIVO_GED
               join agdown in db.ARQUIVOGEDLOGDOWNLOAD on new { X = aglv.ID_ARQUIVO_GED, Y = aglv.ID_USUARIO } equals new { X =                   join agdown.ID_ARQUIVO_GED, Y = agdown.ID_USUARIO } into lfjvd
               join epu in db.EMPRESAPORUSUARIO on aglv.ID_USUARIO equals epu.ID_USUARIO
               join emp in db.EMPRESA on epu.ID_EMPRESA equals emp.ID_EMPRESA
               join up in db.USUARIOPESSOA on aglv.ID_USUARIO equals up.ID_USUARIO
               join pes in db.PESSOA on up.ID_PESSOA equals pes.ID_PESSOA
               from lj in lfjvd.DefaultIfEmpty()
          where
               (dataVisualizacao != null ? EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(aglv.DT_VISUALIZACAO) == dataVisualizacao : true) &&
               (dataPublicacao != null ? EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(ag.DT_CRIACAO) == dataPublicacao : true) &&
               (idUsuario != null ? aglv.ID_USUARIO == idUsuario : true) &&
               (lstPreenchido != false ? lstIdsUsuariosEmpres.Contains(aglv.ID_USUARIO) : true) &&

  //THIS IS IGNORED///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
  --> (nomeArquivo != string.Empty ? ag.DS_ARQUIVO.Contains(nomeArquivo) : true) ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                                                                    


  select new RetornoLogViewGED
  {
   NM_PESSOA = pes.NM_PESSOA,
   NU_CPF = pes.NU_CPF,
   REVENDA = emp.NM_FANTASIA,
   NOME_ARQUIVO = ag.DS_ARQUIVO,
   DT_VISUALIZACAO = aglv.DT_VISUALIZACAO,
   DT_CRIACAO = ag.DT_CRIACAO,
   DT_DOWNLOAD = lj.DT_VISUALIZACAO
  });
```

But when I send a value in the variable "nomeArquivo" seeking a term on the base, he ignores and not just applying this filter. Is there something wrong in the order of joins? Or the order of Where? The value of variable "nomeArquivo" is "lion" for example, because the condition is only executed when the value of this variable is not empty (String.Empty)

can someone help me with this? Or have been through something similar?

Already grateful!

Comment: Have you tried a minimal example with less joins? Maybe it is yet another EF bug, I already run into some.

Comment: Is this Linq-to-Entity? If so can you include the SQL statement that gets generated? And what dataprovider you are using.

Comment: Yes it is, where I caught the command (SQL statement)? 
DataProvider - Oracle OleDB

Comment: You have to activate sql output in the configuration file. Google it if you don't know how to ;-)

Comment: I have not found anything native EF itself. Would have to create something in his hand. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: In the 4th condition you have `lstPreenchido` and `lstIdsUsuariosEmpres`. Is that related to your problem? BTW you can write the conditions as `(nomeArquivo == string.Empty || ag.DS_ARQUIVO.Contains(nomeArquivo))`.